# Is there a better way to make build in one step in iOS development?

Tags: ios, build-automation

In Joel test, I have seen a section named, "Can you make a build in one step?".
I typically build the code suing Xcode and archive it. Is there a way better than this to do in case of iOS development?

EDIT:

Is there any way to build using a build script?
The current way I follow is to use Product -> Archive for generating builds.
Is there a better way here to reduce the time?

Comment: See [this](http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/better-build-phase-scripts/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose `Product -> Archive` in Xcode, it will build the app and archive it for you. That's one step. It's not clear what you're looking for that would qualify as "better".

Edit: in recent versions of Xcode (5.0+, possibly earlier), you can use `xcodebuild archive` on the command line to build and archive your app, just as Xcode would do it.